# Customize the Flutter TextField text selection button

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm looking for a way to customize the flutter's text selection panel(e.g. copy, paste, select all). Especially, I want to add events for onCopy and onPaste actions.

Comment: As far I know those are not native and theoretically, it's possible. But I didn't find a way.

Answer (score 0):

Create on `longPressed` on InkWell or GestureDetector.
inside `longPressed` create `showMenu`

Example: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58334342/8822337

**Or**

You can user Selectable Widget. [click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSU3ZXOs6hc&list=PLjxrf2q8roU23XGwz3Km7sQZFTdB996iG&index=56)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
SelectableText(
    'Your Text',
    toolBarOptions: ToolBarOptions(copy: true,)
)
```

For more info,
https://youtu.be/ZSU3ZXOs6hc