# Textformfield selection controls in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, textformfield

This image shows flutter app selection controls
[image: img]

But I want selection controls like Gmail.
[image: Gmail selection control]
How can I made it.

Comment: Your question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58334097/how-to-change-text-selection-option-in-flutter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change text selection option in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58334097/how-to-change-text-selection-option-in-flutter)