# Flutter: Showing Text Selection toolbar onTap apart from long press

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have created TextField like below

```
TextField(
  inputFormatters: [
    AppConstants.defaultPhoneInputFormatter
  ],
  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
  controller: phoneController,
  onTap: () {
   ///... any suggestion
  },
)
```

What should I do inside the onTap method of above TextField so that TextSelection controls appear onTap, just like they appear on long press.

[image]

Can we do this leveraging built-in Text controls without using custom popup?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58334097/how-to-change-text-selection-option-in-flutter

Comment: @AwiasRehman Thanks! using custom menu is one of option but implementing that is a headache lot of different use case if I leverage build controls then it will be great.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not do that exactly, but you can "override" long press function:

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_textfieldFocusNode);
        showMenu...
    },
    onLongPress: () {
        showMenu...
    },
    child: IgnorePointer(
        child: TextField(
            focusNode: _textfieldFocusNode,
            controller: _controller,
        ),
    )
)
```

And use [Clipboard class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/Clipboard-class.html) to paste