# Android text options in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I want the selected text in a flutter app to have the options that appear in android apps like select all, copy, cut, translate, share, and other options from installed dictionaries.

The Text, SelectableText and EditField Widgets do not have this functionality.

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58334097/how-to-change-text-selection-option-in-flutter

Comment: Yes, this is the same as my question, but the answer is not convincing.